# Compiled python executable access blocked to access Oracle database

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, oracle11g, cx-oracle

I have a script (my_script.py) that accesses an Oracle database with the typical logon process via cx_Oracle.

```
def make_connect(**creds):
    dsn_str = cx_Oracle.makedsn(host, port, sid)
    return cx_Oracle.connect(un, pw, dsn_str)
```

There is no problem accessing the database through this method when the script is run from an IDE, but as soon as I package it into an executable (with PyInstaller, although I don't think this matters), I am getting the following error:

`ORA-20045: LOGON BLOCKED`

I believe this is because the executable that is accessing the database is not python.exe that is running the code but rather my_script.exe.  The code works as expected if I change my_script.exe to python.exe, meaning I believe python.exe is whitelisted by the database for access.

I don't know enough about what particular system variable or environ variable declares itself to the Oracle database for access, but I have tried changing sys.executable to python.exe, or sys.argv[0] to python.exe, but I think there is something deeper that I might need to change (if I could change anything at all to get access).

Any suggestions would be more than helpful.  The exe will be on systems with domain access to the database but because it's only python.exe that is whitelisted their access will be denied.

Comment: Oracle exceptions in the ORA-20000 to ORA-21299 range are generic **user-defined exceptions** raised by calling `raise_application_error`. You might have a LOGON trigger or something similar that's preventing you from connecting. Try running this query to look for the code that's generating this error: `select * from all_source where text like '%-20045%'`

Comment: Ask your DBAs to change the trigger to check the driver name that initiated the connection instead of the program name.  This will be (very) marginally more secure but much less annoying to users: `SELECT UNIQUE sid, client_driver FROM v$session_connect_info ORDER BY sid;` The de facto standard for the CLIENT_DRIVER column is 'name : version'.  Note older versions of the DB will only show the first 9 or so characters that the driver actually sets, so you might not see the version when you use Oracle DB 11.

Comment: And by "marginally more secure" I mean "marginally less insecure", since anyone can fake the binary name (as you were doing) or the driver name.